# How to resize controls inside groupbox without overlapping?

Tags: c#, anchor, windows-forms-designer, dock

Consider I have a simple group box with two textboxes

[image]

When I expand the window I want to resize the my label and textbox. So I used the Anchor property, but it is getting overlapped. Textbox1 is overlapping with textbox2.

[image]

How can I maintain the size increase based on form size without overlapping

Comment: You want only textbox1 to increase in size or both?

Comment: @MatSnow Both..

Comment: Then i suggest to use a TableLayoutPanel with 4 columns.

Comment: Can i add TableLayoutPanel inside groupbox. I tried doing it but it didn't allow me to add TableLayoutPanel inside groupbox. Will check again

Comment: Yes, you should be able to add it inside GroupBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want like this:

1. Add a TableLayoutPanel with 4 columns and place it inside your GroupBox.
2. Place the Labels inside columns 1/3 and Textboxes inside columns 2/4
3. Set `SizeType` of columns 1/3 to `Autosize` and 2/4 to `50%`
4. Set the `Anchor`-property of the TableLayoutPanel to `Top, Left, Right`
5. Set the Textboxes and Labels `Dock`-property to `Fill`
6. Set the Labels `TextAlign`-property to `MiddleLeft`