# Calculate and set location of label at design time

Tags: c#, visual-studio

On a form I got a TabControl, and above this a Label.
I always want the label to appear centered above the TabControl.
The width of the TabControl changes (with anchors) if the width of the form is changed.
Now I want the position (location) of the label to be adjusted accordingly.

At runtime this is easy:

```
//Position headline label
lblHeadline.Left = tabControl1.Left + (tabControl1.Width / 2) - (lblHeadline.Width / 2);
```

But how do I get Visual Studio to do this at design time, so if the width of the form is changed from the properties window, the label's position is automatically recalculated?

Comment: Winforms is based on `Pixel` *not* `Vectors` as opposed to WPF. Thus, design time changes won't be as dynamic as you want it to be

Answer (score 0):

Winforms aren't that dynamic at design time, like @o_O alreday mentioned in his comment.

But in your case there's no need to center the `Label` programmically.

Like following, the label-Text will also be centered at design time:

- Set the `AutoSize`-Property of the Label to `False`
- Adjust the width of the Label to the same width as the TabControl
- Set the `Anchor`-Property of the Label to `Top, Left, Right`
- Set the `TextAlign`-Property of the Label to `TopCenter`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Left and right of the label there are other components placed, thus the label would overlap with these in case I make the label that wide.

Comment: Then you can use a TableLayoutPanel. I've answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316025/how-to-resize-controls-inside-groupbox-without-overlapping/46316465#46316465) some days ago;